# Show that a subset of a given function space is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**STATEMENT:** Define a norm, $N$, on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ by
$$N(f)=||{f}||_\infty+L(f)$$
Let $D=\left\{f\in\mathcal{L}_b(X):N(f)\leq 1\right\}$. Prove that when $X$ is compact and $D$ is viewed as a subset of $C(X)$, then $D$ is totally bounded for the metric on $C(X)$ from the supremum norm $||\cdot||_\infty$.

**NOTE:** that $L_b(X)\subseteq L(X)\subseteq C(X,\mathbb{R})$ where $X$ is a compact metric space, and $L_b(X)$ is the subset of bounded Lipschitz functions. Also $L(f)$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$. $\mathcal{L}(f)$ is the set of Lipschitz functions.

**QUESTION:** I have prove it using a method that doesn't involved the Arzela Ascoli theorem, but I was wondering how you would prove it using Arzela Ascoli.

Comment: What is $L(f)$? And $\mathcal L(X)$?

Comment: $L(f)$ is the lipschitz content and $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is the set of Lipschitz functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\lVert f\rVert_\infty\leqslant 1$ for each $f\in D$ hence $D$ is bounded. It is equicontinuous since  $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant |x-y|$$
for each $x,y\in X$ and each $f\in D$.

Comment: But how do we show that $D$ is closed? Since Arzela-Ascoli states that D has compact closure iff D is equicontinuous and point wise bounded.

Comment: The questions asks for totally bounded (maybe it is an extra question).

Comment: I apologize for my incompetence, but how does the above answer show that D is totally bounded? I may be misunderstanding how Arzela-Ascoli is utilized here.

Comment: The set $D$ is bounded and equi-continuous, so it is relatively compact (by Arzela-Ascoli). Relative compactness is equivalent to total boundedness.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks.